# j8583 How to get debugString after parseMessage

Tags: j8583

When I get the `debugString()` of an `IsoMessage` that I build, it works fine, but when I try to get the `debugString()` of an `IsoMessage` that was created by parsing (`mf.parseMessage(..)`) the `debugString()` is empty.
The parsing works fine, and the field values are there, but the `debugString()` returns empty string.

Am I missing something?

Isn't it possible to print the debugString of a parsedMessage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be Eclipse's console.
The debugString starts with a non printable character which seems to cause the problem.
When run standalone, the debugString gets printed ok like this:

^@p023060180...

(Notice the ^@p at the begining).

Answer (score 0):

Any message should be able to print its `debugString`. This must be a bug.

**UPDATE** so this is weird, because I just added a simple test to check for this, and it passes:

https://github.com/chochos/j8583/commit/3a32b9041470c31a451791f3baa082f18204504a

Comment: Strange. I'm using version 1.10.2, because 1.11.0 does not work with java 1.6. Let me see if I can create a test case.